# sharp architecture question - no strongly typed views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to get my head around the sharp architecture and used the visual studio template as described on the web:

http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/VSTemplatesAndCodeGen.ashx

This is all cool. Unfortunately, I cannot add a strongly typed view as easily as I am used to ‘under’ asp.net mvc.

What can I do to ‘enable’ this in VS 2008 Prof? I have also installed asp.net mvc 2.0 and would like to reflect this in my ‘vs studio sharp environment’.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Best wishes,

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this which did the trick:

http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture/browse_thread/thread/43c5131456719b39/cae8904a0a8f2c0e?lnk=gst&q=view+template#cae8904a0a8f2c0e

Comment: The file (Bla.Web) can be found here:

\Projects\Bla\app\Bla.Web